# How to obtain csrf token for a python POST request to Django server

Tags: python, django, post, http-post, django-csrf

Without the csrf token I am getting a 403 Response, so it looks like I need it. I am currently trying to do this:

```
import requests
import sys

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/toasterinfo'

client = requests.session()

# Retrieve the CSRF token first
client.get(URL)  # sets cookie
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrf']
r = client.post(URL, data={'number': 12524,
  'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show', "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken}, headers=dict(Referer=URL))
print(r)
```

Yet I am getting an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django_client.py", line 10, in <module>
    csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 327, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 398, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSRF Token is a **client to server** security feature to protect your users from a cross-site request forgery.

You are doing a server to server request so the CSRF is useless. You should consider removing the requirement for the CSRF and using a proper authentification method for your server to server request.

You can remove the CSRF token verification used the following decorator on your view.

@csrf_exempt

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/views/decorators/csrf/#csrf_exempt

A token based authentification method with an HTTPS connexion would probably fit your case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the safest way but you could add a decorator to that view to exclude the CSRF verification and your POST won't fail.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import requires_csrf_token

@requires_csrf_token
def your_view(request):
    # your code...
```

This solution only applies if you are aware of the risks removing the CSRF verification.